# Force sorting json in PHP

Tags: php, json, sorting

How can I sort label in order:

```
1080p
720p
480p
360p
```

I've tried all Sorting Arrays in PHP documentation and some another "User Defined" sorting functions, but no luck, it shows completely random, not in order.
**My original json:**

```
[{"file":"***","label":"360p","default":"true","type":"video\/mp4"},
{"file":"***","label":"720p","type":"video\/mp4"},
{"file":"***","label":"1080p","type":"video\/mp4"},
{"file":"***","label":"480p","type":"video\/mp4"}]
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the "p" and then sorting?

Comment: Remove "p" from the element with `explode()` of each label of the array, then use `intval()` function to get int value of the string. Then sort by depending index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are using [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to achieve desired output.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/812429)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$json='[{"file":"***","label":"360p","default":"true","type":"video\/mp4"},
{"file":"***","label":"720p","type":"video\/mp4"},
{"file":"***","label":"1080p","type":"video\/mp4"},
{"file":"***","label":"480p","type":"video\/mp4"}]';
$array=json_decode($json,true);

usort($array, function($value1,$value2){
    $value1["label"]=rtrim($value1["label"],"p");
    $value2["label"]=rtrim($value2["label"],"p");

    return $value1["label"]<$value2["label"];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks pretty straight forward to me, you use a custom comparison function for the sorting:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(<<<JSON
[{"file":"***","label":"360p","default":"true","type":"video\/mp4"},
{"file":"***","label":"720p","type":"video\/mp4"},
{"file":"***","label":"1080p","type":"video\/mp4"},
{"file":"***","label":"480p","type":"video\/mp4"}]
JSON
);

usort($data, function($a, $b) {
  return intval($a->label) < intval($b->label);
});
print_r($data);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [file] => ***
            [label] => 1080p
            [type] => video/mp4
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [file] => ***
            [label] => 720p
            [type] => video/mp4
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [file] => ***
            [label] => 480p
            [type] => video/mp4
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [file] => ***
            [label] => 360p
            [default] => true
            [type] => video/mp4
        )

)
```

Comment: Really thanks for your help, but Sahil's answer already solved my problem.

Comment: @ScottWillsleans You should use this method in your project.  There is no need to declare/overwrite variables on each iteration of `usort()`  This is the more concise solution.

Answer (score -1):

First you must decode the JSON string using [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Second sort the decoded array using [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

```
<?php
$array = json_decode($json);
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    $valueA = (int) $a->label;
    $valueB = (int) $b->label;
    if ($valueA == $valueB) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($valueA < $valueB) ? -1 : 1;
});
```